# ls command directory listing and file size

Tags: excel, linux, bash, csv

I listed directory information using the following command ls -lrt * > testinformat.csv.

[ls command to list directory information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnyhW.png)

So this is fine but I want to transform the information in folders to show  summary information like below:

[ls command information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnMvP.png)

I basically want to summarize the total size into one file e.g 018 folder size to the file shown as opposed to listing all the files from step 1 above. Can one do this via bash or should I use excel?I want to automate the process. Thanks

Samantha

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: `du -sh dir` may give you a useable figure. Consult `man du` or `du --help` for other options for output. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Shelter , the issue is that I have many sub directories I want to list data from. Samantha